# Finding most occurrences in set of prolog rules

Tags: prolog

I can't seem to wrap my head around how Prolog actually works. I'm very used to other programming languages like Java and Python but Prolog seems to be very different since it is based on a set of logical statements.

If someone can explain to me how I would approach a situation where I am given a set of rules such as

```
likes(john,mary).
likes(mary,adam).
likes(adam,mary).
likes(jack,destiny).
likes(destiny,adam).
likes(brianna,adam).
```

and I want to find out how to see who is the most liked person (in this case adam = 3), how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's easier if you think of Prolog as a special database retrieval language that can morph into functional programming in the same line.

Here we we have a relation `likes/2` over which we want to run statistics.

One could use predicates from `library(aggregate)` or similar, but let's not

Suggestion is to chain three operations:

1. Create a nicer structure to run stats
2. Run stats over nicer structure
3. Find the best

**Create nicer structure to run stats**

Collect

- the vector (in the form or a Prolog list) of persons that occur as second argument in predicate `likes/2` (so that we have something to count), and
- the set of persons (also in the form of a Prolog list) so that we can iterate over something.

The key are the collection predicates [`findall/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) and [`setof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)

- `findall/3` is used to collect all the `Person` that appear on second argument position of `likes/2`,
- `setof/3` is used to collect the *set* of all `Person` that appear on first or second argument position of `likes/2`.
  To make that work, `setof/3` needs to be told that the argument on the other position is unimportant by
  "existentially quantifying" it with `X^`.

```
person_occurrences(PersonVec) :- 
   findall(Person,likes(_,Person),PersonVec).
   
person_set(PersonSet) :-
   setof(Person,X^(likes(Person,X);likes(X,Person)),PersonSet).
```

Alternativey for `person_set/2`, more comprehensible:

```
person(Person) :- likes(Person,_).
person(Person) :- likes(X,Person).

person_set(PersonSet) :- setof(Person,person(Person),PersonSet).
```

Trying this on the "Prolog Toplevel" shows we are on the right track:

```
?- person_occurrences(PersonSet).
PersonSet = [mary, adam, mary, destiny, adam, adam].

?- person_set(PersonSet).
PersonSet = [adam, brianna, destiny, jack, john, mary].
```

We can easily count how often a person occurs in the vector of persons,
by using `findall/3` to create an arbitrary list of `x` (for example),
one `x` for each occurrence, then determining the length of that list:

```
count(Person,PersonVec,Count) :-
   findall(x,member(Person,PersonVec),Xs),length(Xs,Count).
```

Trying this on the "Prolog Toplevel" shows we are on the right track:

```
?- person_occurrences(PersonVec),count(mary,PersonVec,Count).
PersonVec = [mary, adam, mary, destiny, adam, adam],
Count = 2.
```

We now have the "nicer structure" that we can use to do stats, namely the
"vector of persons" and the "set of persons".

**Run stats over nicer structure**

The result here, called `Stats` shall be a list (it's always lists) of
*pairs* `-(NumberOfOccurrencesOfPersonInPersonVector,Person)`,
which can be more easily written "infix": `Count-Person`, for example `2-mary`.

This is a recursive definition (or an inductive definition) whereby we "count"
for each person element in `PersonSet` until the `PersonSet` is the empty set
(or rather, the empty list), upon which we are done and succeed. The result
is constructed in the third argument:

```
% stats(PersonVec,PersonSet,Stats)

stats(_,[],[]).

stats(PersonVec,[Person|MorePersons],[Count-Person|MoreStats]) :-
     count(Person,PersonVec,Count),           % count them
     stats(PersonVec,MorePersons,MoreStats).  % recursion
```

Trying this on the "Prolog Toplevel" shows we are on the right track:

```
?- person_occurrences(PersonVec),stats(PersonVec,[mary],Stats).
PersonVec = [mary, adam, mary, destiny, adam, adam],
Stats = [2-mary] ;   % Maybe more solutions?
false.               % Nope.
```

New we can build the whole of the stats list:

```
stats(Stats) :- 
   person_occurrences(PersonVec),
   person_set(PersonSet),
   stats(PersonVec,PersonSet,Stats).
```

Trying this on the "Prolog Toplevel" shows we are on the right track:

```
?- stats(Stats).
Stats = [3-adam, 0-brianna, 1-destiny, 0-jack, 0-john, 2-mary] ;
false.
```

**Find the best**

Given `Stats`, we can find a `BestPerson` by maximizing over the list of pairs.

This can be done directly by selecting the pair which is "largest"
according to "the standard order of term": the numeric count comes first
so a term with a larger numeric count is "larger" than one with a
smaller numeric count, which is what we want. The predicate
[`max_member/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=max_member/2)
does what we want:

```
best(Stats,BestPerson,BestCount) :-
   max_member(BestCount-BestPerson,Statss).
```

Alternatively, we can program-out the `max_member/2` (and keep
it to numeric comparison of the first argument, AND get several
answers in case there are several persons with the same "likes"
count), like so:

```
% start the maximization over Stats with a dummy "(-1)-nobody"

best(Stats,BestPerson,BestCount) :-
   best2(Stats, (-1)-nobody, BestCount-BestPerson).

% best2(Stats,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result).

best2([],BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar).

best2([Count-_|MoreStats],BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result) :-
   Count < BestCountSoFar,
   best2(MoreStats,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result). % keep best
   
best2([Count-_|MoreStats],BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result) :-
   Count == BestCountSoFar,
   best2(MoreStats,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result). % keep best (2nd possibility below)
   
best2([Count-Person|MoreStats],BestCountSoFar-_,Result) :-
   Count >= BestCountSoFar,
   best2(MoreStats,Count-Person,Result). % take new, better, pair
```

**Conclude**

We run it together:

```
?- stats(Stats),best(Stats,BestPerson,BestCount).
Stats = [3-adam, 0-brianna, 1-destiny, 0-jack, 0-john, 2-mary],
BestPerson = adam, BestCount = 3 ;  % maybe more solutions?
false.                              % no
```

### Complete code

```
likes(john,mary).
likes(mary,adam).
likes(adam,mary).
likes(jack,destiny).
likes(destiny,adam).
likes(brianna,adam).

person_occurrences(PersonVec) :- 
   findall(Person,likes(_,Person),PersonVec).
   
person_set(PersonSet) :-
   setof(Person,X^(likes(Person,X);likes(X,Person)),PersonSet).

count(Person,PersonVec,Count) :- 
   findall(x,member(Person,PersonVec),Xs),length(Xs,Count).

% stats(PersonVec,PersonSet,Stats)
   
stats(_,[],[]).

stats(PersonVec,[Person|MorePersons],[Count-Person|MoreStats]) :-
     count(Person,PersonVec,Count),           % count them
     stats(PersonVec,MorePersons,MoreStats).  % recursion
   
stats(Stats) :- 
   person_occurrences(PersonVec),
   person_set(PersonSet),
   stats(PersonVec,PersonSet,Stats).
   
% start the maximization over Stats with a dummy "(-1)-nobody"

best(Stats,BestPerson,BestCount) :-
   best2(Stats, (-1)-nobody, BestCount-BestPerson).

% best2(Stats,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result).

best2([],BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar).

best2([Count-_|MoreStats],BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result) :-
   Count < BestCountSoFar,
   best2(MoreStats,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result). % keep best
   
best2([Count-_|MoreStats],BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result) :-
   Count == BestCountSoFar,
   best2(MoreStats,BestCountSoFar-BestPersonSoFar,Result). % keep best (2nd possibility below)
   
best2([Count-Person|MoreStats],BestCountSoFar-_,Result) :-
   Count >= BestCountSoFar,
   best2(MoreStats,Count-Person,Result). % take new, better, pair
```

Comment: I always let me desire for efficiency from imperative languages bleed into the solution. A shorter solution where we "make Prolog work for us" below!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set of facts:

```
likes(john,mary).
likes(mary,adam).
likes(adam,mary).
likes(jack,destiny).
likes(destiny,adam).
likes(brianna,adam).
```

**Another possible solution** is as follows:

You can use `setof/3` to get the list of persons that like someone:

```
?- setof(Person, likes(Person,Someone), ListOfPersons).
Someone = adam,
ListOfPersons = [brianna, destiny, mary] ;
Someone = destiny,
ListOfPersons = [jack] ;
Someone = mary,
ListOfPersons = [adam, john].
```

Then, you can combine `setof/3` with `findall/3` to get a list of pairs of the form `Someone-ListOfPersons`:

```
?- findall(Someone-ListOfPersons, setof(Person, likes(Person,Someone), ListOfPersons), Pairs).
Pairs = [adam-[brianna, destiny, mary], destiny-[jack], mary-[adam, john]].
```

After that, you can use `maplist/3` to map pairs of the form `Someone-ListOfPersons` into corresponding pairs of the form `Someone-NumberOfPersons`:

```
?- findall(Someone-ListOfPersons, setof(Person, likes(Person,Someone), ListOfPersons), Pairs), 
   maplist([Someone-ListOfPersons, Someone-NumberOfPersons]>>length(ListOfPersons,NumberOfPersons), Pairs, NewPairs).
Pairs = [adam-[brianna, destiny, mary], destiny-[jack], mary-[adam, john]],
NewPairs = [adam-3, destiny-1, mary-2].
```

Finally, you can use `sort/4` to get the most liked person:

```
?- findall(Someone-ListOfPersons, setof(Person, likes(Person,Someone), ListOfPersons), Pairs), 
   maplist([Someone-ListOfPersons, Someone-NumberOfPersons]>>length(ListOfPersons,NumberOfPersons), Pairs, NewPairs), 
   sort(2,>=,NewPairs, SortedPairs).
Pairs = [adam-[brianna, destiny, mary], destiny-[jack], mary-[adam, john]],
NewPairs = [adam-3, destiny-1, mary-2],
SortedPairs = [adam-3, mary-2, destiny-1].
```

Thus, the **final solution** is:

```
most_liked(Person) :-
   findall(Someone-ListOfPersons, 
           setof(Person, likes(Person,Someone), ListOfPersons), 
           Pairs), 
   maplist([Someone-ListOfPersons, Someone-NumberOfPersons]>>length(ListOfPersons, NumberOfPersons), 
           Pairs, 
           NewPairs), 
   sort(2, >=, NewPairs, [Person-_|_]).
```

Running example:

```
?- most_liked(Person).
Person = adam.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution where we don't care about the admonition to "do things only once" and "let Prolog work for us" instead is simply this:

**Determine how much an arbitrary person is "liked"**

```
person_liked_count(Person,Count) :- 
   likes(_,Person),      % Grab a Person
   findall(x,            % Create a list of 'x'
      likes(_,Person),   % one 'x' for each like of the Person  
      Xs),               % and this will be list 'Xs'.
   length(Xs,Count).     % The number of likes is the length of the list
```

We now get multiple solutions for any person, but we don't care:

```
?- person_liked_count(Person,Count).
Person = mary,    Count = 2 ;
Person = adam,    Count = 3 ;
Person = mary,    Count = 2 ;
Person = destiny, Count = 1 ;
Person = adam,    Count = 3 ;
Person = adam,    Count = 3.
```

**Maximize by doing exactly what is demanded**

`Person` with "likes count" `Count` is what we want if we have `person_liked_count(Person,Count)` and there is no other person that has higher count (there is no need to even check that `_PersonOther` is different from `Person` inside the negation-as-failure-marked-subgoal, although we can):

```
most_liked(Person,Count) :-
   person_liked_count(Person,Count),      % grab a Person and a Count
   \+ (person_liked_count(_P,CountOther),  % "where not exists" a person _P
       CountOther > Count).               % with a higher count
```

We now get several answers, but that is not a problem as they are all the same:

```
?- most_liked(Person,Count).
Person = adam, Count = 3 ;
Person = adam, Count = 3 ;
Person = adam, Count = 3.
```

We can always force determinism with once/1

```
?- once(most_liked(Person,Count)).
Person = adam, Count = 3.
```

**Everything in one block**

```
likes(john,mary).
likes(mary,adam).
likes(adam,mary).
likes(jack,destiny).
likes(destiny,adam).
likes(brianna,adam).

person_liked_count(Person,Count) :- 
   likes(_,Person),      % Grab a Person
   findall(x,            % Create a list of 'x'
      likes(_,Person),   % one 'x' for each like of the Person  
      Xs),               % and this will be list 'Xs'.
   length(Xs,Count).     % The number of likes is the length of the list

most_liked(Person,Count) :-
   person_liked_count(Person,Count),      % grab a Person and a Count
   \+ (person_liked_count(_P,CountOther),  % "where not exists" a person _P
       CountOther > Count).               % with a higher count
       
solution(Person,Count) :- once(most_liked(Person,Count)).
```